# Bootstrap 3 Panels not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, panel

I want create panels with Twitter Bootstrap in rails app.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

According to the official doc, we will get like this:

[image]

but I just get the text.

```
Panel heading without title
Panel content
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't check right now, but it definitively worked some time ago. May you add exact version of the bootstrap which you are using. And try to update to the latest stable version (if you are using other one).

Comment: How are you including Bootstrap? Gem? CDN? Less? Sass?

Comment: it works when I update to the latest version, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the Gemfile.

```
# gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" 
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' # install the lastest version
```

then `bundle install` to install the latest version.